# Diagram software that allows you to connect a line to another line?

Tags: diagram

I need a diagramming software with the following characteristics.

-The objects that can be drawn are a Circle (with caption in it), a straight line, and a one-direction arrow.
-Lines can link circles, but it can also link to a line (very important).
-Two circles can be linked or adhered to each other.
-The diagramming software is free to use (at least for non commercial) and does not expire.

I must be able to easily draw a diagram such as this.

[image: Diagram]

I have looked around and most of the free ones have one problem: You can't connect a line to a line or an arrow to a line. You must connect a line to a circle.

The only one which was able to connect a line to another line had an expiration date and you had to purchase it.

So please let me know if you know of such a tool.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the answer: Microsoft Word.